# InternetExplorer COMException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMexception: The RPC server is unavailable

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I'm very new to C# so please excuse me if it's a silly question.

I created a console application that uses the "InternetExplorer" from SHDocVw. This application goes to a website and performs some operations. It works just fine on my computer, but when I try to publish it I just can't to get it to work on my colleagues computers. These other computers don't have dotnet core installed.

So if I publish the app as framework-dependant I get a hostfxr.dll missing library error and it obviously doesn't work at all.

I thought I could fix this by publishing the app as self-dependant. This didn't help either. I always need to paste the "Interop.MSHTML.dll" and "Interop.SHDocVw.dll" manually. When I do, the app at least starts. Internet explorer shows up, the "Navigate" command works. But as soon as I try to hide the window, or try to work with elements in the page, it just crashes.

There are two types of errors I get:

1. `Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMexception: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
   at SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2.set_Visible(Boolean pBool)
   at MyWebApp.IEDriver.Visibility(Boolean isVisible)
   at MyWebApp.Program.Main(String[] args)`
2. Other times I get a very similar error, but it's even mentions my own user files, even when running on a different machine. Is that normal?

`Unhandled exception. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): The RPC server is unavailable. (0x800706BA)
   at SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass.get_ReadyState()
   at IEAutomation.IEDriver.WaitForComplete() in C:\Users\St3ve\source\repos\MyWebApp\MyWebApp\IEDriver.cs:line 552
   at TestWeb.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\St3ve\source\repos\MyWebApp\MyWebApp\Program.cs:line 82`

I tried to to google the errors, but can't get it work, I would be really grateful for any hints or help.

Comment: can you share the code snippet, where these errors are taking place. For ex: Are these placed in try-catch block ? it says unhandled exception

Comment: also check  Open services.msc using Windows Run. In Windows Services, Verify that Remote Procedure Call (RPC) is running

Comment: Hi @Clint thank you very much for having a look. I checked the RPC service before and now again and it is running.

One of the error comes at calling:   `public void WaitForComplete()
  {
   while (Convert.ToString(IE.ReadyState) !="READYSTATE_COMPLETE" || IE.Busy ==true)
   {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
  }`
The app fails to even retrieve the IE.ReadyState
Is this snippet helpful at all?

Comment: what is the error at IE.ReadyState ?

Comment: can you share the necessary code for us to reproduce the issue at our end ?

Comment: The "RPC server is unavailable." error suggests that the "other machines" do not have access to the "RPC server" for remote procedure calls. This could be a security access issue. It could also mean that the environment of the "other machines" simply lack the required RPC servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of this approach is to make sure we are accessing the right `InternetExplorer` object that is associated with our process

```
private InternetExplorer _IE; 

public Process m_Proc = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "-nomerge www.google.com");

public IEDriver()
{


    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    _IE = null;
    ShellWindows m_IEFoundBrowsers = new ShellWindows();
    foreach (InternetExplorer Browser in m_IEFoundBrowsers)
    {
    if (Browser.HWND == (int)m_Proc.MainWindowHandle)
    {
    _IE = Browser;
    break;
    }
}
```

Then in your methods like WaitForCompleteNew(), Navigate(), etc where ever you attempt to access InternetExplorer's proprties or methods, you can use object _IE.

```
_IE.Visible = false;
document = ((HTMLDocument)_IE.Document)
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help :) after couple hours of trial and error it really seems that the root cause of mine issue was that the incorrect object was selected. Identifying while initiating didn't really fix it though. To make the app work somewhat reliably I added this loop to each method that I use. Now it's working better and it doesn't seem to affect the performance :)